Issue with Custom Converter Not Being Called in Spring Data R2DBC
I’m currently working with Spring Data R2DBC and facing an issue where my custom converter is not being invoked. Here’s the setup:
I have a DAO interface defined as follows:
@Repository
public interface PayDao extends R2dbcRepository<Pay, Long> {

    @Query("""
        select
            p.*,
            u.id uid, u.name, u.age, u.email, u.sex
        from t_pay p left join user u on p.user_id=u.id
        where p.id=:id
        """)
    Mono<Pay> findById(@Param("id") Long id);
}

And a custom converter implemented like this:
@ReadingConverter
public class MyPayConverter implements Converter<Row, Pay> {

    @Override
    public Pay convert(Row source) {
        System.out.println("log：" + source);
        Pay pay = new Pay();
        pay.setId(source.get("id", Integer.class));
        pay.setPayNo(source.get("pay_no", String.class));
        pay.setOrderNo(source.get("order_no", String.class));
        pay.setUserId(source.get("user_id", Integer.class));
        pay.setAmount(source.get("amount", BigDecimal.class));
        pay.setDeleted(source.get("deleted", Integer.class));
        pay.setCreateTime(source.get("create_time", LocalDateTime.class));
        pay.setUpdateTime(source.get("update_time", LocalDateTime.class));

        User user = new User();
        user.setId(source.get("uid", Integer.class));
        user.setName(source.get("name", String.class));
        user.setAge(source.get("age", Integer.class));
        user.setEmail(source.get("email", String.class));
        user.setSex(source.get("sex", Integer.class));

        pay.setUser(user);

        return pay;
    }
}

I’ve also configured the custom converter in my application context:
@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcRepositories
public class R2DBCConfig {
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public R2dbcCustomConversions r2dbcCustomConversions() {
        return R2dbcCustomConversions.of(MySqlDialect.INSTANCE, new MyPayConverter());
    }
}

In my test code, I’m calling the method from my DAO directly without using PayDao:
@Autowired
private PayDao payDao;

@Test
void test5() throws Exception {
    payDao.findById(6L).subscribe(v -> System.out.println("pay:" + v));
    System.in.read();
}

However, the converter doesn’t seem to be called during the test, as there’s no log output in the console, and the user field in the Pay object is always null despite the SQL query returning the correct data when run directly in the database.
I’ve verified that the converter exists in R2dbcCustomConversions, but it’s not being triggered. I’m using Spring Boot version 3.2.0. Any insights on why the converter might not be working or how to debug this further would be greatly appreciated.
